# "Access Denied, you need ModifyAccount to modify this page" but I have aws-portal:ModifyAccount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have just started with a new company and I need to modify contact info on AWS. Any attempt gives me the error

> Access Denied, you need ModifyAccount to modify this page.

I have given my user that the following policy with no luck.

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "aws-portal:*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have also attempted a policy with just

> aws-portal:modfiyAccount

and a policy allowing all actions on all resources. What is stopping me from modifying `contact info` on AWS account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tasks that require root user credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html)

**Tasks**

1. `Change your account settings`. This includes the account name, email address, root user password, and root user access keys. Other account settings, such as contact information, payment currency preference, and Regions, do not require root user credentials.
2. `Restore IAM user permissions`. If the only IAM administrator accidentally revokes their own permissions, you can sign in as the root user to edit policies and restore those permissions.
3. Activate IAM access to the Billing and Cost Management console.
4. `View certain tax invoices`. An IAM user with the `aws-portal:ViewBilling` permission can view and download VAT invoices from AWS Europe, but not AWS Inc or Amazon Internet Services Pvt. Ltd (AISPL).

and so on .

Comment: Root user can also Activate IAM Access  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html#ControllingAccessWebsite-Activate